# Jmeter - form elements are not passed over to server as POST parameters

Tags: post, hash, parameters, jmeter

In Jmeter, I am trying to send form data on a web app. But the form elements are not passed over to server as POST parameters. Instead the Hash value is sent. This is making it difficult to parameterize our tests. Any ideas how to get around it?

Comment: Can you provide some code?

Comment: POST Parameters are as follows:
"Name: Hash" "Value: Hex value" "Encode: Enabled"

I would normally expect variable names and values that I can parameterize. But all I can see is a hash value.